# Is it possible to steal any data in an application by forcing to extract a dump file from a running process and analyzing it?

Tags: security, dump

If I have an executable file (no source file/header file and pdb file), and I want to steal or get any possible information from that exe file via analyzing dump file (both raw or through a tool), is it possible? And in what should I do in the code to prevent anyone from getting any sensitive information from my application?

Answer (score 0):

In a dump (User Mode memory dump) you have all process virtual memory as is. So, let's say, if you store some passwords or credit card data in memory, this data can be extracted from memory. If it's not a .Net app and you don't have proper pdb files it makes is a bit difficult but not impossible to find this information.
If you want to protect you data in memory - use appropriate technics like `System.Security.SecureString` in .NET or DPAPI directly.